# Twitter Bootstrap: Buttons not displaying right in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap

Good Day

I am using Twitter Bootstrap, and for some reason in IE (all versions), the background of the buttons (http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#buttonDropdowns) get cut of right below the text. See attached image.

Now when I load the bootstrap website, the buttons show fine, but on my website, it cuts off the background - Only in IE, not in other browsers.

I do use the HTML5 doctype.

What can the issue be?

[image: Twitter Bootstrap Button Issue]

Comment: NOTE: I did not use any custom CSS or changed any of the css in the bootstrap.css file

Comment: Can you please add your code to your question?

Comment: Thanks, but there was issues in my bootstrap.css file. Just redownloaded the css file and replaced it. Working fine now. Must have been custom code that messed up the css file...